# can't into OnChar() when deal with WM_KEYDOWN in 'PreTranslateMessage' function

Tags: visual-c++

For some reason, I need to do something when I get `WM_KEYDOWN message` in `PreTranslateMessage`, So I do something like this:

```
if(WM_KEYDOWN == pMsg->message && pMsg->hwnd == GetSafeHwnd())
{      
     SendMessage(pMsg->message,pMsg->wParam,pMsg->lParam);
     return TRUE;       
}
```

After doing so, I find there is no way to get into `OnChar` function, It's bad.
Anybody knows why and how to solve this problem? Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a dialog based application? and your PreTranslateMessage and OnChar is in the dialog class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return TRUE from PreTranslateMessage() then the message won't be processed further.  You do this for *every* keystroke, so none will be processed and can never generate a WM_CHAR message.  In other words, you got what you ask for.  It also looks like you are sending the message to yourself.  Hard to suggest an alternative, the code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks very mush, I have got the answer after reading 'OnChar' topic, and why I send the message to itself is that I have write the right function to deal with key-down message long time ago， but I found it can't process it correctly when I show the control on a modeless dialog, So I use GetMessage hook to dispatch PreTranslateMsg function and deal with key-down message like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why will you send the same message to yourself? If all you want to do is do some processing and let the message pass through all you need to do in the 'if' statement is do your processing and let the normal message chaining work. This way the message will dispatched for further processing and eventually reach your onChar.

so your code should be something like this:

```
void YourWnd::PreTranslateMessage(MSG *pMsg)
{
    if(WM_KEYDOWN == pMsg->message && pMsg->hwnd == GetSafeHwnd())
    {      
         processKeyDown();      
    }
    return CWnd::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why PreTranslateMessage? What possible reason would you have to do it in PreTranslateMessage?

PreTranslateMessage as the name suggests pretlanslate messages containing hot/shortcut keys.
Using it as some kind of a bandage very frequently leads to disaster sooner or later.

Could you please tell us what you are trying to achieve? Somebody will be able to come up with better solution.

Comment: we know that "Modeless Dialog Box in a DLL Does Not Process TAB Key", I use some thick that make the "PreTranlateMessage" function can get the key down message, so I send the message to itself.